# If a discount is pre-tax or post-tax then what is this quality of being one or the other called?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a discount is pre-tax or post-tax then what is the name of the general concept of being one or the other called?

I am looking for a word that would describe the chronological positioning of the discount relative to the taxing - an elegant version of "position relative to taxing". Maybe something in the vein the word "weight" or "order", but that could be postfixed to the word tax- without implying a scale that refers to the tax itself.

Comment: *In context*, many people would probably understand *Is the discount **gross** or **net[t]**?* to mean ***before** or **after** applying tax / shipping costs / etc. to the item price*. Same as the difference between ***gross pay / net pay***, where the second version means ***after** paying tax and any other stoppages*.

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine a post-tax discount. The nearest thing I can think of is when the seller covers the VAT. I've seen this advertised as 0% VAT (not very accurate, but does get the point across) and *we pay the VAT* (or words to that effect). It's not strictly post-tax, because the VAT is calculated on the net price, but I can't think what other kind of arrangement you could have in mind.

Comment: There is only inclusive or exclusive of tax or subtotal [never include tax]

Comment: Interesting point @FumbleFingers except that I am referring specifically to tax only and net / gross implies, I believe, all peripheral charges. Moving forward, what I specifically need is a word that describe this state's (pre-tax / post-tax) quality.

Comment: @Minty - this could be in a case where I don't even advertise the VAT in my store but the customer's payment covers it. I just want to show the customer a discount offer, but in a financial report, I have to state that this discount was effected post-tax.

Comment: In English, in a financial report, this would be covered by tax-inclusive and tax-exclusive income or sales revenue. It's interesting to me that you do not seem to be interested in answers that reflect the real world...

Comment: In other words you put the sale through at full price, generating the maximum tax liability, then give the customer some money, which you set off against the post-tax sale price? I don't understand why you would do that. A *discount* is a reduction in price, which means it comes before tax. That's why there isn't a modifier to indicate whether it is applied before or after tax. *Rebate* might be a better word, but you would still have to specify that it was *post-tax*...

Comment: ... and I think it would be a good idea to check that this arrangement is even possible under the applicable tax / sales law.

Comment: @Minty Of course,discounts are before tax.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "Is this discount **taxable**?"

In this case, the discount is taxable if the discount is taken post-tax, and is not taxable if the discount is taken pre-tax.

> The taxable amount of your charges to your customers is called the taxable receipt.

[Taxable receipt](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pubs_and_bulls/tg_bulletins/st/taxable_receipt.htm)

Comment: I have never heard that. A discount is not said to be taxable or untaxable. A total amount is taxable, with or without a discount.

Comment: Thanks @Damila. Well, what I require, as I wrote in my question, is a word describing the _quality_ being pre- or pos- tax. Would you therefore describe this quality as the discount's "taxablity"? And if so what would be the taxability grade of a pre-tax and post-tax discount? Would you say that "the discount's taxability" is "pre-tax"?

Answer (score 0):

discounts are applied to the price of an item before tax.

When you lay out the price structure you get:

- item price
  [sub-total]
- tax
  [total]

> That is, you have a sub-total prior to charging the person for the
>   tax. That sub-total is tax exclusive.

As far as I know, there is no such thing as post-tax discount for retail or wholesale widgets, at least in the U.S. In Europe, you will see: tax excl. of tax (which is often the value-added tax).

Discounts are calculated on the sub-total (or subtotal) amount in retail/wholesale areas. In other words, they are tax exclusive.

However, in tax accounting, one gets the concepts of:
tax-inclusive and tax-exclusive sales tax rate

> Sales tax rates are typically quoted in tax-exclusive terms, but
>   income tax rates are typically quoted as tax inclusive. For example, a
>   household that earns $130 and pays $30 in income taxes would normally
>   think of itself as facing roughly a 23 percent ($30 ÷ $130) income tax
>   rate. [tax-exclusive and tax-inclusive](https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/briefing-book/what-difference-between-tax-exclusive-and-tax-inclusive-sales-tax-rate)

Comment: I think you can have a post-tax discount using an item-specific coupon at the end of a sale as part payment. So although in real-life terms it's a payment, in technical terms, in a system that abstracts all promotions as "discounts", this would resolve to a post-tax discount.

Comment: @nzn Sale coupons generally apply to pre-tax (subtotal) amounts. They are not post-tax. At least not in any economic, business or retail reality I am familiar with.